# why the variable value 'F', when web scraped changes to 'FALSE'

Tags: r

Here is the issue i observed when i web scraped a table as shown in the image, it changes the value to 'FALSE', is there a way to avoid it while web scraping. I am using the rvest package

[image]

```r
call_link <- "https://www.cdisc.org/standards/therapeutic-areas/vaccines/vaccines-therapeutic-area-user-guide-v11/html"
call_page <- read_html(call_link)

call_table <- call_page %>% html_nodes("table.confluenceTable.dataset") %>% 
  html_table() %>% .[[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `html_table(convert = FALSE)`.

Comment: Since R likes its single-letter abbreviations, I wouldn't be surprised if a lone `T` somewhere were similarly converted into `TRUE`.

Comment: `call_page %>% html_element('table.dataset:contains("Temperature")') %>% html_table(convert = F)`   - an alternative way to target the table of interest